# rule identifier failed predicate

Tags: groovy, apache-pig

recently, i tried to do some pig script with groovy, here is my code

```
def appID = ['pub000000', 'pub000004', 'pub000001', 'pub000004'] as Object[]
before :appInfo = new Object[4]
now: **def appInfo = ['info1','info2','info3','info4']**

for (int i = 0; i < appInfo.size(); i++) {
    //Load all the related appInfo tables 
    pigServer.registerQuery("${appInfo[i]} = LOAD'hbase://Information.${appID[i]}' " +
                            "USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('meta:number1 "  +
                            "meta:number2') " +
                            "AS (number1:chararray, number2:chararray);")
}

pigServer.registerQuery("totalAppinfo = UNION ${appInfo[0]},${appInfo[1]},${appInfo[2]},${appInfo[3]};")
```

I worked it out finally, just to give the array the value.

Comment: I think the issue is the `${appInfo[i]}` at the start of the `registerQuery` in the for loop.  This evaluates to `null` as the `appInfo` array is empty.  Not sure what it should be...

Comment: Finally, i worked it out.

Comment: Hi tim_yate,sorry i forgot to reply this, i have already reedit my post, you see the line begins with "now", that's my solution, i should give value to this list before i use it

Comment: Cool, updated my answer with a version that should work too then ;-)  Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete guess (never used piglatin), but does this work?

```
def appID = ['pub000000', 'pub000004', 'pub000001', 'pub000004']

appID.each { id ->
    pigServer.registerQuery( "${id} = LOAD'hbase://Information.${id}' " +
                             "USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('meta:number1 "  +
                             "meta:number2') " +
                             "AS (number1:chararray, number2:chararray);")
}

pigServer.registerQuery("totalAppinfo = UNION ${appId.join(',')};")
```

#### Edit after update to question:

```
def appID = ['pub000000', 'pub000004', 'pub000001', 'pub000004']
def appInfo = ['info1','info2','info3','info4']

[appInfo,appID].transpose().each { info, id ->
    pigServer.registerQuery( "${info} = LOAD'hbase://Information.${id}' " +
                             "USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('meta:number1 "  +
                             "meta:number2') " +
                             "AS (number1:chararray, number2:chararray);")
}

pigServer.registerQuery("totalAppinfo = UNION ${appInfo.join(',')};")
```

Comment: hi tim_yates,thanks so much for this response, i tried this but it seemed not getting the right answer, i'm just new to groovy, btw why don't you create another array to store the result, i'm not quite get this actually

Comment: and in PIG, union works to put all the tables together, means i have 4 tables,each has 10 lines, then union can return a table with 40 lines